How to specify directories to use for linting/formatting?
There is a src option that tells ruff to resolve relative paths in specified directories. There is also an include option that allows specifying file patterns to check.
But is there an option to specify to execute linting/formatting only in specified directories? Searching in documentation/googling didn't help.

For these purposes you can just list the directories you need to include.
ruff check 'your-dir/' 'your_dir2/' ...

Official documentation:
Run Ruff on the given files or directories (default)

Usage: ruff check [OPTIONS] [FILES]...

Arguments:
  [FILES]...  List of files or directories to check [default: .]


ruff <PATH> has long been deprecated and replaced with ruff check <PATH>. Also, there's no --src command line option.

Sorry, didn't know. Will edit my answer

Thanks, but my answer is not about excluding, but rather about specifying what to include.
I want ruff lint/format in certain folders, but not anywhere else.

Got it. Updated my answer
